# ConcurrentModificationException thrown while removing element from the list

Tags: codenameone

I have to remove the element from the list which I'm iterating from the storage. It will throw ConcurrentModificationException even with Iterator usage. This code will execute at the end of activity. Refer : iter1.remove(). Please suggest if there is any work around for it.

```
List<OfflineCommand> l_loc = (List<OfflineCommand>) Storage.getInstance().readObject("LocationTest"); 
            if (l_loc != null) {                
                boolean flgSuccess = true;
                ListIterator<OfflineCommand> iter1 = l_loc.listIterator();
                while (iter1.hasNext()) {
                    OfflineCommand oc = iter1.next();
                    flgSuccess = executeOfflineCommand(oc);
                    if (!flgSuccess) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        iter1.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
```

In another place , I'm using following code to add entry to the same list for every minute.

```
 List<OfflineCommand> l_noAppt = Storage.getInstance().readObject("LocationTest");
            if (l_noAppt == null) {
                l_noAppt = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            l_noAppt.add(new OfflineCommand(name, args));
            Storage.getInstance().writeObject("LocationTest", l_noAppt);
```

Comment: First you say that your code **will** throw the exception. Then you say you are **not sure** if it will throw an exception. You contradict yourself. Please explain.

Comment: I could n't predict which is causing the issue. I have added code where I'm using the list in my project. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Adding element on one place and removing on another place simultaneously needs synchronization.

**A) Use *Vector*.**

Vector provides synchronization out of the box. But even for Vector, *don't use Iterator* because you have concurrent modifications.

```
// On the place where you create your list now, create a Vector,
// like ... = new Vector<...>() instead of ... = new ArrayList<...>().
// Just a cast is not sufficient of course.
Vector<OfflineCommand> l_loc = ...;
if (l_loc != null) {                
  boolean flgSuccess = true;
  while (!l_loc.isEmpty()) {
    OfflineCommand oc = l_loc.get(0);
    flgSuccess = executeOfflineCommand(oc);
    if (!flgSuccess) {
      break;
    } else {
      l_loc.remove(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Advantage: You don't need explicit synchronization. Your code remains compact.

**B) Use explicit synchronization.**

```
List<OfflineCommand> l_loc = ...;
if (l_loc != null) {                
  boolean flgSuccess = true;
  while (!l_loc.isEmpty()) {
    OfflineCommand oc = l_loc.get(0);
    flgSuccess = executeOfflineCommand(oc);
    if (!flgSuccess) {
      break;
    } else {
      synchronized (l_loc) {
        l_loc.remove(0);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Important: On the place where you add objects into this list you should also use synchronization:

```
synchronized(l_loc) {
  l_loc.add(...);
}
```

The 2nd approach is not so reliable, because you should keep in mind all the places where your list can be modified and use synchronization there.

Both these approaches, A and B, will solve the problem with concurrent modification.

Comment: Thank You mentallurg. I'm gonna try the Vector approach to see if this works. Thanks

Comment: IT didn't work either. still throwing ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: @user1678742: Show your code. I suppose have just replaced List with Vector and kept Iterator. Right? Don't use **Iterator**. In my example I don't use it. Vector correctly works when many threads concurrently add or remove elements to it.  But **Iterator** of **Vector** does not accept concurrent modifications. Don't use **Iterator**. Instead use any normal loop construct: **while**, **do**, **for**.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Those are two separate list instances. He does need to make sure they are both running in the same thread so they write/read from the storage without overwriting each other

Comment: @Schai Almog: Have you read the question? In another thread every minute new elements are added. You don't understand the requirements. This is namely the requirement that this should work correctly **with concurrent modifications**.

Comment: Another place not another thread. Since operations are synchronized on the EDT that's unlikely  I think it's related to his issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51092728/executeofflinecommand-skips-a-command-while-executing-from-storage

Comment: @Shai: 1. Don't guess. Ask the author. 2. In the post you refere it is clear that another thread is used. How you think adding to the queue is done?

Comment: No. See the section on invokeAndBlock https://www.codenameone.com/manual/edt.html It can create a situation where the EDT is processing a blocking operation while doing something else in the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague.
To avoid ConcurrentModificationException, use a ConcurrentHashMap and use a FOR loop instead.

Answer (score -1):

Once `remove()` is invoked the `Iterator` instance becomes invalid. There are several workarounds for this. Since you remove all elements up until an unsuccessful entry something like this would work `iter1 = l_loc.listIterator();` or in context:

```
            while (iter1.hasNext()) {
                OfflineCommand oc = iter1.next();
                flgSuccess = executeOfflineCommand(oc);
                if (!flgSuccess) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    iter1.remove();
                    iter1 = l_loc.listIterator();
                }
            }
```

Comment: No. Your statement is wrong. After invoking **remove** iterator stays **valid**.

Comment: @Shai - as the error will be thrown at statement iter1.remove(), adding iter1 = l_loc.listIterator(); will not help as the error was thrown by then. Please advise.

Comment: @Shai. will the vector work well with Storage in CN1. Please advise.

Comment: Did you actually try this? The next cycle after the first remove() is the thing that fails.

Comment: Yes Shai. I have tried and it started failing again. Is there any other alternative to this. Thanks

Comment: Which line throws the concurrent modification exception

Comment: At this line exception is being thrown : iter1.remove(); Please advise.

Comment: @Shai...is there any work-around for this ? Please advise.

Comment: Sure use a flag before entering the loop to block yourself from going into the loop twice

Comment: @Shai Why would the loop executes twice?  can you explain.

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Is the method code is reached twice where do you guard against double execution?