# executeOfflineCommand skips a command while executing from storage on Android

Tags: codenameone

I have to execute "Start" and "Finish" Commands in the Sequential Order in my program and synchronize everything at the end. So I'm inserting the Offline commands in the order first and assuming they will execute in the same order. I'm using "List" with "Iterator" for this.

Problem here is: Finish Command will be missed execution in some strange scenarios in the middle and "start" commands will execute next to each other and sending all wrong data and mapped it in a wrong way.

As action will get ID when command executes at the server, I'm keeping tempory id's to map the offline commands in storage(localID). Instaead of List if I use anyother collection will this gets any better? It is hard to reproducing this on simulator. Please review both scenarios and advise where can this approaches go wrong. Thanks

I will add the OfflineCommands into the List and save in the Storage. After that user can perform delete delete operation in the App so that I will retrieve the list and remove the commands which got deleted from storage so now I have filtered list.

Answer (score 0):

Don't synchronize.

That's nearly always a mistake in Codename One. Your code deals with the UI so it should be on the EDT and `Display.getInstance().isEDT()` should be true.

My guess is that one of the commands in the middle uses one of the following `invokeAndBlock()` derivatives:

- `addToQueueAndWait`
- Modal dialogs

Which triggers a second round of synchronization to run.

You can trace that by reproducing the issue and checking which command in the list is specifically there at each time. Then fix that command so it doesn't block in this way.

Another approach to fixing it is to remove the list immediately when you start processing which will prevent a duplicate execution of commands.

Comment: Shai..I'm little confused. can you provide little more details. I'm using addToQueueAndWait for every query I make to retrieve the results. Please refer the additional code attached in the ticket.

Comment: Second Approach can give give an example, you mean removing the list after processing or before. IF I do before how can I access the elements. Please advise.

Comment: I'm using NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(r); for every query I made from my App.

Comment: I'm deleting the storage file when all the commands executed successfully  if 
Storage.getInstance().deleteStorageFile("list2"); Please advise.

Comment: @Shai..do I have to replace addToQueueAndWait(r) with addToQueue(r)? I have depenency of first action and second action. I need the first action need to complete before second one starts. This is happening mainly on android devices.Please advise.

Comment: I ahve added UI-dialog code and Network code with addToQueueAndWait(r) as well. All other server request I'm using addToQueueAndWait(r) including location polling which happens every 4 minutes.

Comment: All the "Start" and "Finish" commands that need to happen in sequential order were part of synchronizeOfflineData()  method  in that last code snippet. Please advise

Comment: You can use addToQueueAndWait() but you need to make sure that the elements you process don't trigger the loop all over again. While addToQueueAndWait is running the code loops again and tries to run the queue over again which would explain the issue you are having. This is blocking the current EDT but the EDT is still running in the background...

Comment: Here the problem is statements are running only once but they are not running in the order they have been inserted. I want to make the commands execute in the same order  that they have been order. Is there any thing I can do it make sure it will happen in both online and offline mode.Please advise. Thanks

Comment: If the order of the commands are in 1,2,3,4 then execute command will do in order 1,3,4.. and never executes 2 and 2 will stay in cache forever.

Comment: I'm using NetworkManager.getInstance().updateThreadCount(2); in init() method will this make the command to skip as well. I'm using 2 threads because I'm consistently polling the location coordinates but not sending to the server. I'm synchronizing at the end only. Sorry for too many comments on this thread. I'm trying to narrow it down as I'm not able to replicate this issue on simulator or my own device. Please advise.

Comment: If you are doing the processing on the network thread with count set to two you can have 2 threads accessing the command in tandem. You should assert that the commands are processed on the EDT (of which there is only one) and have a flag that marks that you are currently processing these commands can code shouldn't be reentered.