# Performing the synchronization with ExecuteOfflineCommand more effectively

Tags: codenameone

I'm wondering is there a way to recognize the OfflineComamd is being executed or internal flag or something to represent this command has been passed or  mark it has been executed successfully. I have issue in recognizing the command is passed or not with unstable internet. I keep retrieve the records from database and comparing each and every time to see this has been passed or not. But due to the flow of my application, I'm finding it very difficult to avoid duplicates.IS there any automatic process to make sure commands executed automatically or something else?

2nd question, I can use UITimer to check isOffline() to make sure internet is connected or not on the forms. Is there something equivalent on server page or where queries is written to see internet is disconnected or not. When the control moved to queries and internet is disconnected I see the dialog open from form page being frozen for unlimited time and will not end. I have to close and re-open the app to continue the synchronization process.At the same time I cannot set a timeout for dialog because I'm not sure how long it will take the complete the Synchronization process. Please advise.

Extending on the same topic but I have created a new issue just to give more clarity on my questions.
[executeOfflineCommand skips a command while executing from storage on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51092728/executeofflinecommand-skips-a-command-while-executing-from-storage-on-android)

Comment: `OfflineCommand` isn't a Codename One class AFAIK. If that class is defined in your project can't you add a flag to it?

Comment: Yes Shai. I did. But the problem is when device continuously going offline and online. How can I identify the command has been executed successfully before device gets disconnected? Is there some thing I can run  like UITimer to make sure connection is active before or during query getting executed. Forgive if this sounds silly question. Please advise.

Comment: See my answer. The problem is offline can happen in the middle of an execution. The only 100% sure way to implement offline/online reliably is with the help of the server.

Comment: Got it. Sure Shai. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to know if a connection will stay stable as it requires knowledge of the future. You can work like transaction services do where the server side processes an offline command as a transaction using the approach of 2-phase commit.

In this approach you have an algorithm similar to this:

- Client sends command to server
- Server returns a special unique ID for the command
- Client asks server to perform the unique id
- Server acknowledges that the command was performed

If the first 2 stages didn't complete you just do that again. The worst thing that could happen is some orphan commands on the server.

If the 3rd option didn't complete you just do it again. The server knows whether it processed the command and will just acknowledge it if it was already processed.